# Using lists inside data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

In `data.table` is possible to have columns of type `list` and I'm trying for the first time to benefit from this feature. I need to store for each row of my table `dt` several comments taken from an rApache web service. Each comment will have a username, datetime, and body item.

Instead of using long strings with some weird, unusual character to separate each message from the others (like `|`), and a `;` to separate each item in a comment, I thought to use lists like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=1:2,
        comment=list(list(
            list(username="michele", date=Sys.time(), message="hello"),
            list(username="michele", date=Sys.time(), message="world")),
          list(
            list(username="michele", date=Sys.time(), message="hello"),
            list(username="michele", date=Sys.time(), message="world"))))

> dt
   id comment
1:  1  <list>
2:  2  <list>
```

to store all the comments added for one particular row. (also because it will be easier to convert to `JSON` later on when I need to send it back to the UI)

However, when I try to simulate how I will be actually filling my table during production (adding single comment to a particular row), `R` either crashes or doesn't assign what I would like and then crashes:

```
library(data.table)

> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(id=1:2, comment=vector(mode="list", length=2))
> dt$comment
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

> dt[1L, comment := 1] # this works
> dt$comment
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
NULL

> set(dt, 1L, "comment", list(1, "a"))  # assign only `1` and when I try to see `dt` R crashes
Warning message:
In set(dt, 1L, "comment", list(1, "a")) :
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'comment' (1 unused)

> dt[1L, comment := list(1, "a")]       # R crashes as soon as I run
> dt[1L, comment := list(list(1, "a"))] # any of these two
```

I know I'm trying to misuse `data.table`, e.g. the way the `j` argument has been designed allows this:

```
dt[1L, c("id", "comment") := list(1, "a")] # lists in RHS are seen as different columns! not parts of one
```

**Question:** So, is there a way to do the assignment I want? Or I just have to take `dt$comment` out in a variable, modify it, and then re-assign the whole column every times I need to do an update?

Comment: You could probably use `rbind` and/or `merge` to succesively update your `data.table`, but that sounds very inefficient. Other than that I can only say that I ran into the following warning message: "Column 'comment' is type 'list' which is not supported as a key column type, currently."

Comment: `dt[1L, comment := list(1L)]` - you've to use `list(.)` as the column type is `list`. `set(dt, 1, "comment", list(1))` - `list(1, "a")` is of length 2, and you're assigning it to `i=1` (which is of length 1.

Comment: @arun can you please write an answer with a reproducible code? because I don't I understood. Just to clarify: I need something like `list(1, "a")` inside 1 cell of the table, precisely in an element of a column of type `list` as defined above

Comment: @shadow I think you need to update `data.table`

Comment: @Arun `I don't I understood` means `I think I haven't understood` sorry... I also tried to assign `list(list(1, "a"))`, which is of length 1, but `R` still crashes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using `:=`:

```
dt = data.table(id = 1:2, comment = vector("list", 2L))

# assign value 1 to just the first column of 'comment'
dt[1L, comment := 1L]

# assign value of 1 and "a" to rows 1 and 2
dt[, comment := list(1, "a")]

# assign value of "a","b" to row 1, and 1 to row 2 for 'comment'
dt[, comment := list(c("a", "b"), 1)]

# assign list(1, "a") to just 1 row of 'comment'
dt[1L, comment := list(list(list(1, "a")))]
```

For the last case, you'll need one more `list` because `data.table` uses `list(.)` to look for values to assign to columns by reference.

Using `set`:

```
dt = data.table(id = 1:2, comment = vector("list", 2L))

# assign value 1 to just the first column of 'comment'
set(dt, i=1L, j="comment", value=1L)

# assign value of 1 and "a" to rows 1 and 2
set(dt, j="comment", value=list(1, "a"))

# assign value of "a","b" to row 1, and 1 to row 2 for 'comment'
set(dt, j="comment", value=list(c("a", "b"), 1))

# assign list(1, "a") to just 1 row of 'comment'
set(dt, i=1L, j="comment", value=list(list(list(1, "a"))))
```

HTH

---

I'm using the current development version 1.9.3, but should just work fine on any other version.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.0.99  reshape2_1.2.2 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks a million, I was missing one `list`, I tried only with 2, not 3. I was misled by `dt[1, comment := 1]` inserting `1` inside the first list element. So I thought `:= list(list(1, "a"))` should put `list(1, "a")` inside the first list element. One question Arun: why `dt[1, comment := list(list(1))]` and `dt[1, comment := 1]` gives the same result?

Comment: @Michele, Great question! I think it shouldn't. It should give a type mismatch error, IIUC. I'm not sure if I'd call it a bug, but it's still an inconsistency. So, could you please file a bug report [**here**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=975&group_id=240&func=browse)?

Comment: awesome. `:= list(list(1, "a")) ` solved my problem. Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Arun, I'm using data.table 1.9.7 and got warnings of type coercion for several example code in `:=`.  And how can I assign a vector to a cell? `dt[, comment := list(c("a", "b"), 1)]` work for all rows, but assigning one cell with `dt[1, comment := list(c("a", "b"))]` or `dt[1, comment := c("a", "b")]` doesn't even give right result.

Comment: OK, the problem is probably with that we need [[]] to access the list item. the regular method of `dt$comment[[1]]  <- c("a", "b")` works. Though I still don't know how to do it in data.table `j` syntax.

Comment: Use `list(list(...))`. The first list is for the syntax. The second one is for your column. See the reference semantics vignette.

Comment: @Arun, I knew the extra list requirement, but I'm trying to use a column of list which hold a vector in each cell, just like Matt's example below. `dt[, comment := list(c("a", "b"), 1)]` is working as I expected, which put a vector in first row, but I'm trying to assign one cell at a time, not for whole column, while `dt[1, comment := list(c("a", "b"))]` doesn't work (it has warning, and the result is not right). I later found out `dt$comment[[1]] <- c("a", "b")` works, but I'm wondering if there is a syntax inside `j` that can work.

Answer (score 19):

Just to add more info, what `list` columns are really designed for is when each cell is itself a `vector`:

```
> DT = data.table(a=1:2, b=list(1:5,1:10))
> DT
   a            b
1: 1    1,2,3,4,5
2: 2 1,2,3,4,5,6,

> sapply(DT$b, length)
[1]  5 10
```

Notice the pretty printing of the vectors in the `b` column.  Those commas are just for display, each cell is actually a vector (as shown by the `sapply` command above). Note also the trailing comma on the 2nd item of `b`. That indicates that the vector is longer than displayed (data.table just displays the first 6 items).

Or, more like your example :

```
> DT = data.table(id=1:2, comment=list( c("michele", Sys.time(), "hello"),
                                        c("michele", Sys.time(), "world") ))
> DT
   id                       comment
1:  1 michele,1395330180.9278,hello
2:  2 michele,1395330180.9281,world
```

What you're trying to do is not only have a `list` column, but put `list` into each cell as well,  which is why `<list>` is being displayed. Additionally if you place *named* lists into each cell then beware that all those names will use up space. Where possible, a `list` column of `vectors` may be easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I think I'll be fine however. I'm not using data.table for its speed (this time).