# Populating a data frame with lists in R

Tags: r, list

I want to populate a column of a data frame with lists. Based on the example code I found [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/populating-data-frame-cells-with-more-than-one-value/):

```
d <- data.frame(id=1:2, name=c("Jon", "Mark"))
d
d$children <-  list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally"))
d
```

I expected that the following code would work:

```
d <- data.frame(id=1:2, name=c("Jon", "Mark"))
d
d["children"] <-  list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally"))
d
```

but it gave the error:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "children", value = list(list("Mary",  :
  provided 2 variables to replace 1 variables
```

Based on reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581189/r-varied-length-vector-or-list-in-variable) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531477/using-lists-inside-data-table-columns/22536321#22536321) I changed the code to this:

```
d <- data.frame(id=1:2, name=c("Jon", "Mark"))
d
d["children"] <-  list(list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally")))
d
```

which worked perfectly. The question is, what is going on here? What does the extra call to `list` accomplish? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things happening here. R produces different behaviors when indexing with single brackets `[ ]` or double brackets `[[ ]]`. In short, when using single-brackets to index into a data frame, R expects (or returns) *list objects*. When using double-brackets, the underlying *vector* is returned.

Note that the first example below, with single-brackets, retains the data frame column's structure and naming, while the double-bracket example returns the column's primitive contents as a vector.

```
> str(mtcars['mpg'])
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ mpg: num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...

> str(mtcars[['mpg']])
 num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
```

To answer your question of why the superfluous call to `list()` helps at all, `str` can shed some light on the matter:

Your original code, without the extra `list()`, is a list of length 2:

```
> str(list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally")))

List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Mary"
  ..$ : chr "James"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Greta"
  ..$ : chr "Sally"
```

This fails because `d['children']` is expecting to be matched to an object with length 1. However, adding the extra `list()` creates an "outer" list of length 1, so the assignment succeeds.

```
str(list(list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally"))))

List of 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "Mary"
  .. ..$ : chr "James"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "Greta"
  .. ..$ : chr "Sally"
```

Finally, your original code (without the extra `list()`) would have worked had you used double-bracket indexing:

```
d[["children"]] <-  list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally"))
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helps! I've accepted your answer, but I'm going to add an answer with additional examples that helped me understand.

Answer (score 0):

@jdobres answer got me playing with the following examples, which helped me understand (kinda) what's going on.

```
> d <- data.frame(id=1:2, name=c("Jon", "Mark"))
> d
  id name
1  1  Jon
2  2 Mark
> add <- list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally"))
> d$children <- add
> d
  id name     children
1  1  Jon  Mary, James
2  2 Mark Greta, Sally
> str(d$children)
List of 2                                  # d$children is a list of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Mary"
  ..$ : chr "James"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Greta"
  ..$ : chr "Sally"
> str(add)
List of 2                                  # add is a list of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Mary"
  ..$ : chr "James"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Greta"
  ..$ : chr "Sally"
```

This works because the lhs and rhs of `d$children <- add` are both lists with 2 items.

```
> d <- data.frame(id=1:2, name=c("Jon", "Mark"))
> d
  id name
1  1  Jon
2  2 Mark
> add <- list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally"))
> d["children"] <- add
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "children", value = list(list("Mary",  :
  provided 2 variables to replace 1 variables
> d
  id name children
1  1  Jon     Mary
2  2 Mark    James
> str(d["children"])
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:     # d["children"] is 1 var. with 2 obs.
 $ children:List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Mary"
  ..$ : chr "James"
> str(add)
List of 2                                  # add is a list of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Mary"
  ..$ : chr "James"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Greta"
  ..$ : chr "Sally"
```

This doesn't work because the lhs of `d$children <- add` is "1 var. with 2 obs." but the rhs is "a list of 2".

```
> d <- data.frame(id=1:2, name=c("Jon", "Mark"))
> add <- list(list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally")))
> d["children"] <- add
> d
  id name     children
1  1  Jon  Mary, James
2  2 Mark Greta, Sally
> str(d["children"])
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:     # d["children"] is 1 var. with 2 obs.
 $ children:List of 2
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "Mary"
  .. ..$ : chr "James"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "Greta"
  .. ..$ : chr "Sally"
> str(add)
List of 1                                  # add is 1 list with 2 lists
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "Mary"
  .. ..$ : chr "James"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "Greta"
  .. ..$ : chr "Sally"
```

The nomenclature is a little illogical here, but if you accept that a list has to be inside a list to count as a list, then the above works because the lhs of `d$children <- add` is "1 var. with 2 obs." and the rhs is "1 list with 2 lists". Note the symmetry 1var:2lists::1list:2lists.

```
> d <- data.frame(id=1:2, name=c("Jon", "Mark"))
> d
  id name
1  1  Jon
2  2 Mark
> add <- list(list("Mary", "James"), list("Greta", "Sally"))
> d[["children"]] <- add
> d
  id name     children
1  1  Jon  Mary, James
2  2 Mark Greta, Sally
> str(d[["children"]])
List of 2                                  # d[["children"]] is a list of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Mary"
  ..$ : chr "James"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Greta"
  ..$ : chr "Sally"
> str(add)
List of 2                                  # add is a list of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Mary"
  ..$ : chr "James"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Greta"
  ..$ : chr "Sally"
```

Like the first example, this works because the lhs and rhs of `d$children <- add` are both lists with 2 items.

I'm still not sure what the enclosing structure of `add` should be called in the cases where `str(add)` evaluates to `List of 2...`, but that might not be important.