# Melt a data.table with a list data type (get lists of values in one col for each unique value in another col)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that looks like this,

```
dt <- data.table(
       cbind(
          id = c( 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 ),
          y = c( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' )
       )
);
```

I would like to transform it to a `data.table` that looks like this:

```
   id   y.list
1:  1    list( a, b )
2:  2    list( c, d )
3:  3    list( e, f, g )
```

The `list` above can be any container, i.e. either a `vector`, a simple `c`, or any other container that can be iterated upon later on. Grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: you don't need the `cbind`... you can go straigth to `dt <- data.table(id = ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> dt = dt[, list(list(y)), by = id]
> dt
   id    V1
1:  1   a,b
2:  2   c,d
3:  3 e,f,g
> class(dt[1, V1])
[1] "list"
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531477/using-lists-inside-data-table-columns) helpful SO question gives some background information on lists within data.table objects.  In particular, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22536321/3541976) response mentions that you need to use the `list(list())` formulation because with a single instance of `list()`, data.table will use it to look for values to assign to columns by reference.

**Extensions**

```
## For all unique values, you can use:
dt = dt[, .(.(unique(y))), by = id] # all unique values

# If you want to write a list column to file. 
# Default separator within the column is |  
# You can specify otherwise with sep2 argument (must be of length 3):
fwrite(dt, Out_FN, sep="\t", sep2 = c("", ";", ""))
```

Comment: Or `dt[, .(.(y)), by = id]` for less typing.