# Adding list columns to data tables in R returns inconsistent output - feature or bug?

Tags: r, data.table

I use `$` to add a list column to a `data.table` in R. When the `data.table` has more than one row, this works as expected.

```
library(data.table)

dt2 <- data.table(x = 1:2)
dt2$y <- list(c(1, 1), c(2, 2))
dt2
#>    x   y
#> 1: 1 1,1
#> 2: 2 2,2
```

However, when the `data.table` has exactly one row, only the first element of the vector in the list is returned with a warning:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = 1)
dt1$y <- list(c(1, 1))
#> Warning in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value): Supplied 2 items
#> to be assigned to 1 items of column 'y' (1 unused)
dt1
#>    x y
#> 1: 1 1
```

This seems inconsistent. Is it a feature or a bug?

By contrast, doing the same thing with `data.frame`s returns the expected output, regardless of the number of rows in the `data.frame`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1)
df1$y <- list(c(1, 1))
df1
#>   x    y
#> 1 1 1, 1

df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:2)
df2$y <- list(c(1, 1), c(2, 2))
df2
#>   x    y
#> 1 1 1, 1
#> 2 2 2, 2
```

Comment: There is a potentially related question [initialize and copy list column in R data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51508680/3817004).

Comment: `packageVersion("data.table")` ?

Answer (score 3):

Besides [Andre Elrico's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51534678/3817004) to use the `[[<-` operator *consistent* behaviour can also be ensured if a double-nested `list()` is used. This will work for the `$<-` operator as well as `data.table`'s  `:=` assignment operator.

#### 2 row case

```
library(data.table)
dt2 <- data.table(x = 1:2)
dt2$y <- list(list(c(1, 1), c(2, 2)))
str(dt2)

dt2 <- data.table(x = 1:2)
dt2[, y := .(.(c(1, 1), c(2, 2)))]
str(dt2)
```

In both variants `str(dt2)` returns the same:

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ x: int  1 2
>  $ y:List of 2
>   ..$ : num  1 1
>   ..$ : num  2 2
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

Please note that in `data.table` syntax `list()` can be abbreviated by `.()`.

For comparison, here is the code which was used by the OP

```
dt2 <- data.table(x = 1:2)
dt2$y <- list(c(1, 1), c(2, 2))
str(dt2)
```

which creates the same structure

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ x: int  1 2
>  $ y:List of 2
>   ..$ : num  1 1
>   ..$ : num  2 2
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

#### 1 row case

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = 1)
dt1$y <- list(list(c(1, 1)))
str(dt1)

dt1 <- data.table(x = 1)
dt1[, y := .(.(c(1, 1)))]
str(dt1)
```

Again, the output of `str(dt1)` is identical for both code variants and also consistent with the 2 row case.

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ x: num 1
>  $ y:List of 1
>   ..$ : num  1 1
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It's a strange behavior. Feel free to open an issue about it. I don't like the `$` anyways due to such problems and its static character.

For lists I like `[[]]`

Get your consistent behavior like this:

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = 1)
dt1[["y"]]<-list(c(1, 1))

dt2 <- data.table(x = 1:2)
dt2[["y"]] <- list(c(1, 1), c(2, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

From `vignette("datatable-intro")`:

> As long as `j` returns a *list*, each element of the list will become a column in the resulting *data.table*.

In your code...

```
dt1 <- data.table(x = 1)
dt1$y <- list(c(1, 1))
```

`list(c(1, 1))` is treated as `j`, and its first element is a length-two vector, interpreted as a length-two column. Since your data.table only has one row, this yields a warning. As noted in Uwe's answer, the way around this is to wrap in an extra `list(...)`.

`vignette("datatable-reference-semantics")` brings up a convenience feature:

> ```
> T[, c("colA", "colB", ...) := list(valA, valB, ...)]
>
> # when you have only one column to assign to you
> # can drop the quotes and list(), for convenience
> DT[, colA := valA]
> ```

And this works in your other code...

```
dt2 <- data.table(x = 1:2)
dt2$y <- list(c(1, 1), c(2, 2))
```

... but falls apart as you noticed in the special case of one row where `valA` should create a list column, so it's better to follow the advice in Uwe's answer: consistently wrapping in an extra `list(...)` or `.(...)`.

Also see "What are the smaller syntax differences between data.frame and data.table?" in `vignette("datatable-faq")` for other differences with data frames.

*Side note*: There's little point using a data.table if you're going to assign like `DT$y <- v`. It kind of defeats the purpose of the package to avoid the syntax that supports modifying the table by reference, namely `DT[, y := v]`...

Comment: The other answers are good, but this point was missing and it seemed too tedious to convince them to add it in, so... posting.