# Assignment in data.table using `:=` has inconsistent behaviour

Tags: r, data.table

Consider a `data.table` dt:

```
library(data.table)
dt  = setDT(structure(list(grp = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
                     yr = c(2000, 2012, 2004, 2008, 2014, 2008, 2016),
                     sal = c(20000, 240000, 30000,100000,120000, 15000, 60000)), 
.Names = c("grp", "yr", "sal"), 
row.names = c(NA,-7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

I have a dummy function `tag` which returns a character value based on some conditions on `sal` and `yr`.

```
tag = function(x){if(x$yr<2010 & x$sal<25000) {return(list(comment="okay"))} 
             else if(x$yr<2010 & x$sal>=25000) {return(list(comment="cool"))} 
             else if(x$yr>=2010 & x$sal<100000){return(list(comment="okay"))} 
             else if(x$yr>=2010 & x$sal>=100000){return(list(comment="cool"))} }
```

All the values returned by the function are enclosed with the `list()` call, so that the returned value can be assigned to a new column `mycomment` in my table `dt`. However, the following two calls behave differently.

```
dt[,mycomment:=tag(.SD),by=1:nrow(dt)]
#mycomment appears as a character vector

dt[,`:=`(mycomment=tag(.SD)),by=1:nrow(dt)]
#mycomment appears as a list
```

What is the reason for difference in the behaviour of the `:=` operator in this case?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think this has to do with the fact that quoting `:=` leads to using it like you would in a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function call for `j` in `x[i, j, ...]` when making an assignment to `x` is

```
`:=`(col1_name = col1, col2_name = col2)

# or

c("col1_name", "col2_name") := list(col1, col2)
```

The second way exists for user convenience (so you don't have to mess with backticks around `:=`). A further convenience is offered when there is a single column:

```
`:=`(col1_name = col1)

# or 

col1_name := list(col1)

# or 

col1_name := col1
```

Here, the final option saves you from having to wrap in `list(...)`. The same convenience feature shows up when `by=` is present. In both cases, the expectation is that `j` evaluates to a list of columns, which is why a bare vector is also treated as a length-one list of columns. If you want to avoid reckoning with this inconsistency, you could always write `list(...)` or always use the `` `:=`(...) `` in `j`.

In your example, this might mean changing your function to return a single column instead of wrapping in `list(...)`. For some other ideas and references to the vignettes included with the package, maybe see [Adding list columns to data tables in R returns inconsistent output - feature or bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51531042/1191259)

Alternately, you could apply the `tag` rule more efficiently with something like a "non-equi join":

```
mDT = data.table(
  yr_up  = c(2010, 2010, Inf, Inf), 
  sal_up = c(25000, Inf, 100000, Inf), 
  value  = c("okay", "cool", "okay", "cool")
)

dt[, cmt := mDT[.SD, on=.(yr_up > yr, sal_up > sal), mult="first"]$value]
```