# How to modify variable of type list (or vector) in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

In below example, I need to assign a list to a `data.table`'s variable `code`, so that  value `list(11,22)` is assigned to `dt$code`. How do I do that?

```
dt <- data.table(1:3)
dt$code <- list()
dt[V1==2, code:=list(11,22)] # does not work
dt[V1==2, code:=.(list(11,22))] # does not work
```

My question is  simpler and  shorter than in the earlier post.
Thanks for the answer:

```
dt[V1==2, code:=list(list((list(11,22)))]   # works !
```

Comment: `dt[V1 == 2, code := list(list(list(11, 12)))]`.
possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531477/using-lists-inside-data-table-columns

Comment: @davide You should use the flagging feature to tag a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using lists inside data.table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531477/using-lists-inside-data-table-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dt[V1==2, code:=list(list(list(11,22)))]  # works !
```

This can also be written as

```
dt[V1==2, code:=.(.(.(11,22)))]
```

which is actually synonymous to

```
dt[V1==2, code:=.(.(c(11,22)))]
```

Note however that in this case, it is a vector, rather than list, that is assigned to variable `code` for `V1==2`.

Note also that it is not possible (as of yet) to do either of these:

```
dt[all(code==c(11,22))] 
dt[, ifelse(all(code==c(11,22)), T, F)]
```

which negates quite abit the value of using vectors as variable types for data.table.

PS. Added  - as per Matt's comment below

The new development release of `data.table` will make this question obsolete. Starting from 1.12.3 release, it will be possible to write either way including `dt[V1==2, code:=list(11,22)]`.

Comment: This has been improved in dev 1.12.3 recently.  See news item 4 :  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md

Comment: @Matt, Do you plan to add functionality to  compare list variables so that we can do this: `dt[code==list(list(list(11,22)))]` ? (this would really boost the use of lists within `data.table`)

Comment: Thanks  @Matt. 1.12.3 will make this question obsolete. Pasted from link above: `> DT[2, B:=letters[9:13]]           # was error, now works > DT[2, B:=.(letters[9:13])]        # was error, now works > DT[2, B:=.(list(letters[9:13]))]  # .(list()) was needed, still works`.       Would it however be possible to do this: `DT[B==letters[9:13]] ` ?

Comment: `DT[B==letters[9:13]]` is technically possible as a vector scan but are you really sure that a multi-column key (or index) is not more appropriate; e.g. `setkey(DT, id1, id2, id3, id4, id5); DT[as.list(letters[9:13)]]` ?