# Error when trying to store list in data.table of length 1

Tags: r, list, vector, data.table, coercion

When trying to store a vector in a data.table, this works only when the data.table has length of more than one.

Please find below a simplified version of the problem

`library(data.table)`

#### Working fine

```r
dt <- data.table( a = c("a", "b"), l = list())
dt$l[[1]] <- c(1:3)
```

#### Results in:

```
   a     l
1: a 1,2,3
2: b
```

#### Producing Error

```r
dt <- data.table( a = c("a"), l = list())
dt$l[[1]] <- c(1:3)
```

> Error in [<-.data.table(x, j = name, value = value) : 
>   Supplied 3 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'l'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

#### Expected result in:

```
   a     l
1: a 1,2,3
```

Comment: With the latest version 1.12.3 of data.table (in development), this problem seems to be gone. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md says *Assigning to one item of a list column no longer requires the RHS to be wrapped with list or .()*

Comment: Relevant [Using lists inside data.table columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531477/using-lists-inside-data-table-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
dt <- data.table(a = "a", l = list())
dt[1L, l := list(list((1:3)))]
```

Results in:

```
   a     l
1: a 1,2,3
```

Comment: Great. Short and simple. Thats it! Thanks!