# Cumulative vector in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
library(data.table)
dat = data.table(j = c(3,8,9,11,10,28), gr = c(9,9,9,9,10,10))
> dat
    j gr
1:  3  9
2:  8  9
3:  9  9
4: 11  9
5: 10 10
6: 28 10
```

There are two groups (specified by 'gr') and they are ordered. Now what I would like to achieve is to create for each row of each group a cumulative vector of values in 'j'. The result should be a `list` column, like this:

```
res_dat = data.table(j = c(3,8,9,11,10,28), gr = c(9,9,9,9,10,10),
                     res = list(3, c(3,8), c(3,8,9), c(3,8,9,11),
                                10, c(10, 28)))
> res_dat
    j gr         res
1:  3  9           3
2:  8  9         3,8
3:  9  9       3,8,9
4: 11  9  3, 8, 9,11
5: 10 10          10
6: 28 10       10,28
```

I tried the following:

First I created a dummy column with the number per row for each group.

```
dat[, tmp:= seq_len(.N), by = gr]
```

My plan was to use that number in order to subset the j vector, but I have not managed. None of these worked:

```
dat[, res := list(j[1:tmp]), by = gr]
dat[, res := list(list(j[1:tmp])), by = gr] # based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531477/using-lists-inside-data-table-columns
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In 1:tmp : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
2: In 1:tmp : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

which does help understand how it fails but I don't know how I can make it succeed. Any ideas?

Comment: One possibility: `dat[, res := .(sapply(seq_len(.N), function(x) j[seq_len(x)])), by = gr]`

Comment: While `Reduce(c, j, accumulate=TRUE)` works on the console, it does not inside the `dat` environment, frustrating. @Henrik's comment is (I believe) the simplest, though I suggest the use of `lapply` or `sapply(., simplify=FALSE)` to preclude corner-case differences.

Comment: @r2evans Wrap it in `list`: `dat[, res2 := .(Reduce(c, j, accumulate=TRUE)), by = gr]`

Comment: Dang it, I thought I had tried that. Thanks @Henrik ... might as well answer with that! It's elegant and `data-table`-canonical. (It seems odd to me that it was taking the list return value and discarding most of it in assignment. The return value from `Reduce(..., accum=T)` is already a `list`, not sure why a double-list is strictly necessary here.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Henrik's answer (and if they come back, I'll happy give this answer to them ... somehow):

```r
dat[, res := .(Reduce(c, j, accumulate=TRUE)), by = gr]
#        j    gr         res
#    <num> <num>      <list>
# 1:     3     9           3
# 2:     8     9         3,8
# 3:     9     9       3,8,9
# 4:    11     9  3, 8, 9,11
# 5:    10    10          10
# 6:    28    10       10,28
```

`Reduce` is similar to `sapply` except that it operates on the current value and results of the previous operation. For instance, we can see

```r
sapply(1:3, function(z) z*2)
# [1] 2 4 6
```

This, unrolled, equates to

```r
1*2 # 2
2*2 # 4
3*2 # 6
```

That is, the calculation on one element of the vector/list is completely independent, never knowing the results from previous iterations.

However, `Reduce` is explicitly given the results of the previous calculation. By default, it will only return the last calculation, which would be analogous to `tail(sapply(...), 1)`:

```r
Reduce(function(prev, this) prev + this*2, 11:13)
# [1] 61
```

That seems a bit obscure ... let's look at all of the interim steps, where the answer above is the last:

```r
Reduce(function(prev, this) prev + this*2, 11:13, accumulate = TRUE)
# [1] 11 35 61
```

In this case (without specifying `init=`, wait for it), the first result is just the first value in `x=`, *not* run through the function. If we unroll this, we'll see

```r
11        # 11 is the first value in x
   _________/
  /
 v
11 + 12*2 # 35
35 + 13*2 # 61
```

Sometimes we need the first value in `x=` to be run through the function, with a starting condition (a first-time value for `prev` when we don't have a previous iteration to use). For that, we can use `init=`; we can think of the use of `init=` by looking at two perfectly-equivalent calls:

```r
Reduce(function(prev, this) prev + this*2, 11:13, accumulate = TRUE)
Reduce(function(prev, this) prev + this*2, 12:13, init = 11, accumulate = TRUE)
# [1] 11 35 61
```

(Without `init=`, Reduce will take the first element of `x=` and assign it to `init=` and remove it from `x=`.)

Now let's say we want the starting condition (injected "previous" value) to be 0, then we would do

```r
Reduce(function(prev, this) prev + this*2, 11:13, init = 0, accumulate = TRUE)
# [1]  0 22 46 72


### unrolled
 0        # 0 is the init= value
   ________/
  /
 v
 0 + 11*2 # 22
22 + 12*2 # 46
46 + 13*2 # 72
```

---

Let's bring that back to this question and this data. I'll inject a `browser()` and change the function a little so that we can look at all intermediate values.

```r
> dat[, res := .(Reduce(function(prev, this) { browser(); c(prev, this); }, j, accumulate=TRUE)), by = gr]
Called from: f(init, x[[i]])
Browse[1]> debug at #1: c(prev, this)
Browse[2]> prev                                    # group `gr=9`, row 2
[1] 3
Browse[2]> this
[1] 8
Browse[2]> c(prev, this)
[1] 3 8
Browse[2]> c                                       # 'c'ontinue

Browse[2]> Called from: f(init, x[[i]])
Browse[1]> debug at #1: c(prev, this)
Browse[2]> prev                                    # group `gr=9`, row 3
[1] 3 8
Browse[2]> this
[1] 9
Browse[2]> c(prev, this)
[1] 3 8 9
Browse[2]> c                                       # 'c'ontinue

Browse[2]> Called from: f(init, x[[i]])
Browse[1]> debug at #1: c(prev, this)
Browse[2]> prev                                    # group `gr=9`, row 4
[1] 3 8 9
Browse[2]> this
[1] 11
Browse[2]> c(prev, this)
[1]  3  8  9 11
Browse[2]> c                                       # 'c'ontinue

Browse[2]> Called from: f(init, x[[i]])
Browse[1]> debug at #1: c(prev, this)
Browse[2]> prev                                    # group `gr=10`, row 6
[1] 10
Browse[2]> this
[1] 28
Browse[2]> c(prev, this)
[1] 10 28
Browse[2]> c                                       # 'c'ontinue
```

Notice how we didn't "see" rows 1 or 5, since they were the `init=` conditions for the reduction (the first `prev` value seen in each group).

`Reduce` can be a difficult function to visualize and work with. When I use it, I almost always pre-insert `browser()` into the anon-function and walk through the first three steps: the first to ensure the `init=` is correct, the second to make sure the anon-function is doing what I think I want with the init and next value, and the third to make sure that it continues properly. This is similar to "Proof by Deduction": the `n`th calc will be correct because we know the `(n-1)th` calc is correct.

Comment: Glad you posted @r2evans! I was busy with my coffee. Cheers

Comment: *highfive* for gender neutral language.

Comment: This is perfect thank you both very much! May I ask that just for posterity you add a brief explanation for the code?

Comment: Does that help explain it?

Comment: That's much more than I had in mind! Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped. I believe `sapply` and `lapply` are relatively straight-forward for most; `apply` is only slightly more to grasp. However, `mapply`/`Map` can be a bit more difficult for some, and `Reduce` can be easily misunderstood. Walking through like this seems to be (imho) a good way to visualize what it is doing under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple `tidyverse` solution, unfortunately I haven't started learning `data.table` but until you get a relevant solution it will do fine:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  mutate(res = accumulate(j[-1], .init = j[1], ~ c(.x, .y)))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   gr [2]
      j    gr res      
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
1     3     9 <dbl [1]>
2     8     9 <dbl [2]>
3     9     9 <dbl [3]>
4    11     9 <dbl [4]>
5    10    10 <dbl [1]>
6    28    10 <dbl [2]>
```

Or in base R we could do:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(dat$gr), function(a) {
  tmp <- subset(dat, gr == a)
  tmp$res <- Reduce(c, tmp$j, accumulate = TRUE)
  tmp
}))
```

Or even this terrific yet concise suggestion by dear @Henrik:

```
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$gr, function(d){
  cbind(d, res = I(Reduce(c, d$j, accumulate=TRUE)))}))
```

Or even this one also by dear @Henrik:

```
dat$res = ave(dat$j, dat$gr, FUN = function(x) Reduce(c, x, accumulate=TRUE))
```